# Rails less url path change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, path, less

Developing a Rails application with the [less-rails gem](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails) I found something unusual :

```
// app/assets/common/css/desktop/typo.less

@font-face{
    font-family:'SomeFont';
    src:url("fonts/db92e416-da16-4ae2-a4c9-378dc24b7952.eot?#iefix");
    // ...
}
```

The requested font is

```
app/assets/common/css/fonts/db92e416-da16-4ae2-a4c9-378dc24b7952.eot
```

This font is compiled with less and the results is  :

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'SomeFont';
   src: url("desktop/fonts/db92e416-da16-4ae2-a4c9-378dc24b7952.eot?#iefix");
   //...
}
```

Do you know why is `desktop/` inserted here ? It surely has to do with the path of the file but I couldn't find anything.

Edit : I am aware of the built-in methods such as `image-url`, `font-url`, ... But I need to keep the organisation this way and to only use the default `url` method.

(simply put : I cannot change the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `font_url`, and put the font in `app/assets/fonts`

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'SomeFont';
   src: font_url("db92e416-da16-4ae2-a4c9-378dc24b7952.eot?#iefix");
   //...
}
```

Comment: Can you try that with the `asset_url` then?

Comment: with `asset-url` it works I will do this but I wanted to keep the files from modifying them ... Thanks :)